# Android Broadcast Reciever to open an intent

Tags: android, android-intent, broadcastreceiver

I have an android app which needs to generate a notification in regular intervals and when we click on the notification the message shown in the notification will be shown inside a TextView inside an activity of the Original application.

For that I've created an **AlarmReceiver.java Class**.

```
public class AlarmReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {

    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) 
    {
        Log.d("ME", "Notification started");

        StrictMode.ThreadPolicy policy = new StrictMode.ThreadPolicy.Builder().permitAll().build();
        StrictMode.setThreadPolicy(policy);


            NotificationCompat.Builder mBuilder = new NotificationCompat.Builder(context)
                                                    .setSmallIcon(R.drawable.ic_noticon)
                                                    .setContentTitle("Notification")
                                                    .setContentText("You have to open app to see this message in detail");


            NotificationManager mNotificationManager = (NotificationManager) context.getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
            mNotificationManager.notify(1, mBuilder.build());


            Intent resultIntent = new Intent("com.app.AlarmBack");
            TaskStackBuilder stackBuilder = TaskStackBuilder.create(context);
            stackBuilder.addParentStack(AlarmBack.class);
            stackBuilder.addNextIntent(resultIntent);
            PendingIntent resultPendingIntent = stackBuilder.getPendingIntent(0,PendingIntent.FLAG_ONE_SHOT);
            mBuilder.setContentIntent(resultPendingIntent);


    }
```

also I've created the class for an intent called **AlarmBack.java**

```
public class AlarmBack extends MainActivity {


TextView tv_alert_back_display;


@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);


    getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.alert_back, frameLayout);
    mDrawerList.setItemChecked(position, true);
    setTitle(mTitle);


    tv_alert_back_display = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.tv_alert_back_display);


    tv_alert_back_display.setText("This is the message that needs your attension");
}}
```

but the problem is that this doesn't work. It's not opening the intent that that want it to open. So, can somebody please help to solve my problem.

Comment: you want to open your activity when the notification is clicked or you want to change the title and content of the notification ?

Comment: @ZubairAkber I want to open activity when the notification is clicked

Comment: have you tried my answer it works for me hope so it will work for you as well

Comment: @ZubairAkber I've question about the solution I've mentioned it in the comment section below your answer to make some clarifications. So Please

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Call this in your AlarmReceiver OnRecieve method

```
int taskID = 1;
NotificationManager notificationManager = (NotificationManager) context.getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
notificationManager.notify(taskID, getNotification(context, "title", "content"));
```

And add this method in your Alarm Receiver

```
private Notification getNotification(Context context, String title, String content) {
    Notification.Builder builder = new Notification.Builder(context);
    builder.setContentTitle(title);
    builder.setContentText(content);
    builder.setSmallIcon(R.drawable.icon_64);
    builder.setAutoCancel(true);
    builder.setDefaults(android.app.Notification.DEFAULT_ALL);


    Intent resultIntent = new Intent(context, SplashActivity.class); //Activity that you want to open
    TaskStackBuilder stackBuilder = TaskStackBuilder.create(context);
    stackBuilder.addParentStack(SplashActivity.class);              // Activity that you want to open
    stackBuilder.addNextIntent(resultIntent);
    PendingIntent resultPendingIntent =
            stackBuilder.getPendingIntent(
                    0,
                    PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT
            );
    builder.setContentIntent(resultPendingIntent);
    return builder.getNotification();
}
```

Comment: the first part of the answer where exactly should i call it

Comment: I'm sorry. is it (the first part of the code) inside AlarmReciever Class OnRecieve void method ?

Comment: the first is in OnRecieve mmethod

Answer (score 1):

You need to call notify() after you set your intent on the builder, not before. Otherwise, the notification created by builder.build() will not have these intents when it is added to the notification manager.

Answer (score 0):

You need to `setContentIntent` for your `NotificationBuilder`:

```
NotificationCompat.Builder builder = new NotificationCompat.Builder(
            context).setSmallIcon(R.drawable.app_icon)
            .setContentTitle("Your Title").setContentText("");

    Intent intent = new Intent(context, YourMainActivity.class);
    intent.setAction(Intent.ACTION_MAIN);
    intent.addCategory(Intent.CATEGORY_LAUNCHER);
    PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(context, 100,
            intent, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);
    builder.setContentIntent(pendingIntent);
```